# can't add a new column to a dataframe in python

Tags: python

pretty simple thing im trying to do here I created a rate by dividing 2 numbers and now I'm trying to add that rate into a dataframe:

```
df['rate'] = rate
```

it gives me this error:

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead
```

so what am I doing wrong here? I tried using .loc too but not working.

Comment: Please add the full code

Comment: Without context, this is a fine, so some more context (code) is essential.

Comment: Also kindly show what the rate variable looks like.

Comment: Are you sure its an error? I think its just a warning

Comment: That is not error. It is jus a warning. It wont cause any problem

Answer (score 1):

You get the above error when you try to update a shallow copy(view) created from another dataframe.

When you try to filter a dataframe using slice or indexing, it is possible that a view is returned instead of a copy of the dataframe and although at times the output may seems to have worked and at times it can be tempting to ignore, it is never a good idea to do so as it may have unwanted side-effects on the output and would be very difficult to debug.

One of the ways to avoid this by taking an explicit copy (using `.copy()`) after filtering the dataframe and making any changes on the filtered data.

We can also use `is_copy()` method to verify if the output of a filtering using slicing or indexing is a copy or a view.

**Useful Reads:**

https://realpython.com/pandas-settingwithcopywarning/

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding a new column in this form:

```
df.loc[:,'rate']=rate
```

It seems the length of rate value is not similar to your dataframe length.
Be sure both are in the same length.